# Is there a decent computer based, multiple video stream capture solution out there?

Tags: video

Recently, on a trip home to my dad's, I experienced some great conversations between him and my grandmother. I really wanted a way to record them.

Here's my thinking: using a laptop connected to two or more webcams, capture them both.

I've looked around a bit and I'm finding that the software out there is either clunky, doesn't capture with good video quality, or doesn't record audio. Virtualdub seems to work well.

I've had thoughts of just using multiple in-expensive camcorders but what appeals to me about the computer solution is that I already have a laptop and a webcam. Also, perhaps the clips will be easier to synchronize

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

**You could just record the entire screen or at least the portion that shows the stream with a program designed to do just that.**

One really popular one **for Mac** is [iShowU HD](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowu-hd/).

One really popular one **for PC** is [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/).

CamStudio is free while iShowU HD isn't. **A free one for Mac** that is pretty good is [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html).